# Calculate cumulative sum with addition and subtraction

Tags: postgresql, cumulative-sum

I have a table in the given format

```
+----+--------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+------------+
| ID | Student Name | Subject   | Add Marks | Sub Marks | Cumulative |
+----+--------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+------------+
| 1  | Adam         | Physics   |        74 |        15 |         59 |
+----+--------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+------------+
| 2  | Adam         | Chemistry |        62 |        11 |        110 |
+----+--------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+------------+
| 3  | Adam         | Maths     |       100 |        10 |        200 |
+----+--------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+------------+
| 4  | Joel         | Maths     |        90 |        10 |         80 |
+----+--------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+------------+
| 5  | Joel         | Physics   |        80 |        15 |        145 |
+----+--------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+------------+
| 6  | Joel         | Chemistry |        65 |        20 |        190 |
+----+--------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+------------+
| 7  | Zampa        | Physics   |        60 |        15 |         45 |
+----+--------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+------------+
```

Calculate the cumulative column for each student as shown 
Cumulative + Add Marks - Sub Marks for each student

Comment: `select name, subject, add_marks - sub_marks from table;`? What's the exact problem?

Comment: That's not it. OP needs to calculate cumulative sum of each student's marks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a work request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adapting solution by Kamil:

```
select
  Student_Name,
  Subject,
  Add_Marks,
  Sub_Marks,
  sum(Add_Marks - Sub_Marks)
    over (partition by Student_Name order by ID) as Cumulative
from students;
```

If there is no `ID` field, one can be created for this query using:

```
select
  Student_Name,
  Subject,
  Add_Marks,
  Sub_Marks,
  sum(Add_Marks - Sub_Marks)
    over (partition by Student_Name order by ID) as Cumulative
from ( select *,row_number() over () as ID from students ) tmpt ;
```

The output BTW is like the OP:

```
student_name      subject   add_marks   sub_marks   cumulative  
Adam    Physics     74  15  59
Adam    Chemistry   62  11  110
Adam    Maths       100 10  200
Joel    Maths       90  10  80
Joel    Physics     80  15  145
Joel    Chemistry   65  20  190
Zampa   Physics     60  15  45
```

Comment: Thanks @Kamil for the base solution.

Comment: Thanks @Dan, the updated solution did the trick

Answer (score 0):

You need a key to `ORDER BY` to achieve the cumulative sum that you expect.
For example I've assigned `id` column to each record and incremented it by 1 starting with 1, so sample data looks like:

```
 id | student_name |  subject  | addmark | submark
----+--------------+-----------+---------+--------
  1 | Adam         | Physics   |      74 |      15
  2 | Adam         | Chemistry |      62 |      11
  3 | Joel         | Maths     |      90 |      10
  4 | Joel         | Physics   |      80 |      15
  5 | Zampa        | Physics   |      60 |      15
```

Table name: `students`.

And then the query would look like:

```
select
  student_name,
  subject,
  addmark,
  submark,
  addmark - submark
          + coalesce(lag(addmark - submark) over (partition by student_name order by id),0) as cumulative
from students;
```

I'm using window function `lag` to get the value from previous row (here is where you need the sorting) and `coalesce` function to properly handle first row for each student, where `lag` returns null to replace it with 0 since addition with null would return null.

**Output**

```
 student_name |  subject  | addmark | submark | cumulative
--------------+-----------+---------+---------+------------
 Adam         | Physics   |      74 |      15 |         59
 Adam         | Chemistry |      62 |      11 |        110
 Joel         | Maths     |      90 |      10 |         80
 Joel         | Physics   |      80 |      15 |        145
 Zampa        | Physics   |      60 |      15 |         45
```

Note: If there would be no `id` column and we would decide to order by `student_name` then cumulative would change, since `Adam | Chemistry` sorts before `Adam | Physics` pair. You could use descending order in this example, but that wouldn't really solve your case in terms of different subjects being added.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. The given solution works fine for the given example, however if I add 1 more row for Adam the output is not correct. Please check my edited question